# Обрезается строка при вставке

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Хорошо, у меня есть следующая строка.

```
ViewBag.EntryFieldName = $"value=\"{Model.Title}\"";
```

Model.Title = Проверка времени

Отладку проводил, в переменную записывается нормально.
Я ее начинаю использовать в HTML коде:

```
<input type="text" name="Title" @ViewBag.EntryFieldName class="form-control" />
```

Когда захожу на сайт вижу от этой строки лишь:
"проверка

```
<input type="text" name="Title" value="&quot;проверка" &#x432;&#x440;&#x435;&#x43c;&#x435;&#x43d;&#x438;&quot;="" class="form-control">
```

Как фиксить?(

Answer (score 1):

Вы же интерполируете строку сами, как я понял:

```
$"value=\"{Model.Title}\"";
```

Почему бы не достать `$"value=\"` и не разместить это сразу внутри тега:

```
<input type="text" name="Title" value="@ViewBag.EntryFieldName" class="form-control" />
```

Этот подход лучше, чем использование `@Html.Raw()`, так вы предотвратите возможность html инъекций.
Так же смущает название переменной `Model`. Если это модель, которая передаётся внутрь `View()` то `ViewBag` здесь совсем не нужен.
Если вам всё же крайне критично, чтобы всё значение переменнной оставалось таким:

```
ViewBag.EntryFieldName = $"value=\"{Model.Title}\"";
```

потому, что вы искользуете её где-то ещё именно в этом виде, то почему бы не создать дополнительную переменную

```
ViewBag.InputValue= Model.Title;
```

для отображения именно в

```
<input type="text" name="Title" value="@ViewBag.InputValue" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, вместо
`<input type="text" name="Title" @ViewBag.EntryFieldName class="form-control" />` следует использовать `<input type="text" name="Title" @Html.Raw(ViewBag.EntryFieldName) class="form-control" />`

!!!!НО ВНИМАНИЕ!!!!
этот html хелпер (@html.raw) может привести к нежелательным, а то и опасным, html инъекциям в ваш код. будьте аккуратны